# How to manage PPI and DPI in responsive deigned

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider Two monitors one 15.5 inch 1920 * 1080 and other 24 inch 1920 * 1080, first have PPI of 72 pixel(Approx) and second 90(Approx). Now If I use media query with resolution 1920 * 1080 in CSS, and set font size 50 pixel, this will good in first monitor but in second monitor this will look small, this is not only limited to font size but also there elements.
I am new to frontend, this part of responsive deigned I am not getting

How to size elements, on different size of monitors with same resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use relative units instead of absolute units. relative units like `em, rem, and %` are based on the size of the parent element or the viewport, which makes them more flexible and responsive to different screen sizes and resolutions.